# Desktop Top Save Location For User Storage?

Tags: node.js, desktop-application, node-webkit

While writing a node-webkit application I came across needing to save users uploaded photos through the built in html file input. I can save photos easy enough where I wish via a nice post here on **[node file uploading](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads)** and node-webkit's **[file dialog changes](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs)** simple enough.

The question really is there a best practice for saving user generated content for a desktop app or is the application folder (OS specific) reasonable to use with say the application  or company name? Security is not much of a concern here in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node-webkit (at this time) has an application folder under under process.env.LOCALAPPPATH (for windows users anyway) which could be used.

Another option which is viable is to use an application directory in the exe directory of the program.

IE for node with process global.

```
var path = require('path');

var appDir = path.dirname( process.execPath ) + path.sep + 'data' + path.sep;
//might produce something like c:\\programs\\node-webkit\\data\\
```